# Insert SQL statement error

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-insert

Hi Im trying to insert data into a database using an insert statement. So basically, the user inputs data into a form and then once the submit button is clicked its meant to get the property_id of the table Property. 
My code is this:

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM review WHERE property_id="'.$id.'"');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$review = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['review']);


 if(mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO review(review) VALUES ('$review')"))
  {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Successfully Updated ');</script>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Error...');</script>
        <?php
 }


}
?>
```

At the top of the page is my other code which is as followed:

```
    <?php

include_once '../db/dbconnect.php';

$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql = 'SELECT* FROM property WHERE property_id="'.$id.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

The code above basically displays all the data for that individual property. Any help would be great.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO review(review) VALUES ('$review')"))` in this line, don't you require the concatenation operator `.` around `$review` to build the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @JonathonOgden What is a concatation Operator?

Comment: `.` is; you use it to build a string like this part of your code: `WHERE property_id="'.$id.'"'` Notice the `.` either side of `$id`, that's how you add the value of `$id` into your `SELECT`. You obviously need to do the same with `$review` if you expect to build a valid SQL statement.

Comment: @JonathonOgden so for example,
 if(mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO review(review) VALUES = "'.$review.'""))

Comment: That won't work, it's still invalid. If this is your code, you've already written code that builds a SQL string which includes a value; look at your `SELECT` statements and how `$id` is added.

Comment: `SELECT*` will also need a space `SELECT *` as that's also invalid.

Comment: You are mixing the mysql_ and mysqli_ APIs. In your first snippet you are using `mysql_query()`

Comment: Do you actually get error messages, or are the values simply not inserted into the database?

Comment: @Philipp not inserting into the db

Comment: Have you used `mysqli_error($mysqli)` to ask the database for errors? Do you get the javascript alert that the error occured?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM review WHERE property_id="'.$id.'"');
```

The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP 5, and totally removed in PHP 7. Don't use them!
Moreover, it's not possible to use `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions together.
Yet another error: you are executing a SELECT query, but you never fetch the results!
**Note**: you don't need to concatenate `$id`. It makes the code harder to read with plenty of useless single and double quotes, and increases the likeliness of a typo. [Just enclose the variables in a double-quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).
You are casting `$id` to an int value. If the field `property_id` is an integer, there is no need to put single quotes around `$id` in the query.

**Updated snippet**:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM review WHERE property_id=$id") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($r = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
   // do something here with the current record $r
}
```

**Your code**:

```
if(mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO review(review) VALUES ('$review')"))
[...]
<script>alert('Error...');</script>
```

When developing, you should display (or write to a log file) the MySQL error message from each failing query. It will make debugging much easier:

```
<script>alert('Error: <?= mysqli_error($mysqli) ?>');</script>
```